# How to Create and Run my own Domain Name Server?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I am little new to web development. I have the following questions to be answered. Currently I am developing a **Social Network website** with my team. All we want is, we need to register our website domain name with **ALL THE DOMAIN EXTENSIONS AND COUNTRY CODES AVAILABLE IN THE WORLD. (BEFORE SOMEONE GET)**

eg: www.example.com, www.example.net, www.example.org, www.example.us, www.example.travel, www.example.lk, www.example.tv, www.example.co.in etc...

(How I realized this, one day I tried to search any available facebook domain extension (facebook.tv, facebook.co.nz like that) but non was available..!)

I tried to buy our domain names via some DNS registration websites, but when we are buying such a large number of domain names and extensions for at least 5 years of period, the **PRICE WAS VERY VERY VERY HIGH..!**

So these are my questions.

**1) Can we create and run our own domain name server? (only for our website)**

**2) If we can, are there any place to register?**

**3) How it would be cost? (any license or registration fees and hardware cost)**

**4) Are there any service available for this purpose for a small price?**

Thank you very much..!

Answer (score 0):

1) Can we create and run our own domain name server? (only for our website)

Answer : You can run your DNS(Domain Name Server), but you need to purchase Domain from Domain Registrar.

2) If we can, are there any place to register?

Answer : Domain registrar is only the place to Register.

3) How it would be cost? (any license or registration fees and hardware cost)

Answer : If you wish to become Domain registrar,then it is very expensive affair and its not our cup of tea. Still you may visit following URL.

https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/accreditation-2012-02-25-en

4) Are there any service available for this purpose for a small price?

Answer : There are no service available at low cost.